# How to create multiple parameters with routeLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am on this active route:

```
companies/:id/departments
```

Now I want to create a new department with this route:

```
companies/:id/departments/create
```

My html for this route change via routeLink is this:

```
 <button [routerLink]="['companies', id, 'departments','create']">create</button>
```

I get this error message when I click the routerLink:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'companies/1/departments/companies/1/departments/create'
```

Its obvious, that my routerLink route is appended to the active route.

How should I rewrite my routerLink to make it work?

Does the router assume that the create route is a child route? It is not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing it to :

```
 <button [routerLink]="['create']">create</button>
```

Comment: Why does this work? When I look at the documentation there is just this (taken from AArias comment): "...or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route..." but I am not able to make a connection between the 'create' and the children of the current activated route because in my case exist no child routing.

Comment: yes it work but... AArias works too. I do not like API`s offering multiple ways this leads to bugs sooner/later on the code or developer side. It seems AArias approach is absolute url and your approach is relative url approach.

Comment: @Pascal it works because your button is only present in the path `/companies/:id/departments` and, as you pointed out, routing to `create` is telling angular to use relative approach, thus generating the correct url `/companies/:id/departments/create`. If the same button was present in all the possible views (for example, in a component present in a sidebar or navbar) you would need to use the absolute url approach as depicted in my answer, as for any other path the relative approach would not be valid. I tend to always use absolute paths as it is less error prone and makes the code reusable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html):

> If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route
> from the root of the app.
>
> If the first segment begins with ./, or
> doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the
> children of the current activated route.
>
> And if the first segment
> begins with ../, the router will go up one level.

So basically, all you need to do is add a forward slash before the first segment:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/companies', id, 'departments','create']">create</button>
```

Comment: Yours worked too but is longer, but you were a bit later ;-) so I upvote it!